# Trying to add custom font to Sphinx-RTD-theme

Tags: python-sphinx

I am in process documenting my python library.  I would like to add custom icons.  I see I can add font awesome icons.  However, I must not be googling very well or...

Is it possible to add custom icons to Sphinx(-rtd-theme)?  If so, is there an example?  I cannot find one.  Thank you.

Comment: There are too many ways to customize a theme, by overriding CSS styles from various locations. I just show one quick example that changes colors but you can change fonts and many more, https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/docs/blob/master/_templates/layout.html#L27

Comment: Thank you very much Lex.  I found [sphinx-design](https://sphinx-design.readthedocs.io/en/rtd-theme/css_classes.html?highlight=avatar#avatars).  It looks like Avatars are what I need.  Sadly, I am trying to get the example working but it cannot find the image.  I have a .md file.  The 404 comes in the html part... but still..

Comment: Before doing customization, learn the generated HTML pages and style files so that you know where to start. If you are not a web developer yourself, you might try to find someone.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I found was the [sphinx-design package](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx_design/)  then using the avatars class with the {div} directive (Myst).  e.g.:

```
:::{div}
<img src="images/whale_trace.png" class="sd-avatar-md sd-border-1">
:::
```

note: i use .md instead of .rst.  Thus, I use the Myst parser.  In order to copy the image over and use the right path, the conf.py file needs to be modified :

```
myst_enable_extensions = ["colon_fence", "html_image"]
```

adding html_image will all resolution of the image.  See [Myst documentation](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/optional.html#images):

```
> Blockquote

HTML parsing to the rescue!

By adding "html_image" to myst_enable_extensions (in the sphinx conf.py configuration file), MySt-Parser will attempt to convert any isolated img tags (i.e. not wrapped in any other HTML) to the internal representation used in sphinx.



_
```